# Procedurally generating tile rooms of a tileset

Tags: game-engine, procedural-generation

I'm currently playing around with developing a game written in OpenGL instead of any popular game engine. This game **revolves** around procedural generation, wherein I need to generate a randomized floor (tileset) built from procedurally generated tiles (rooms), using a player defined (or random) seed, which'd provide the same resulting tileset each time used.

I found it difficult to generate such randomized tiles.

#### Let's consider this image a layout of such a room where the color black represents the room's surface and white stands for free space (beyond the player accessible area):

[tile image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz7Gy.png)

Perlin noise I played around with doesn't necessarily generate an image with a **singular** *ink blob* that would touch at least one side of the image, which is what would be required for me to generate a tileset (requiring all tiles to be uniformly sized and have at least one entrance).

If you'd enlighten me on how to handle this particular problem, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely no one correct way to handle this. When dealing with random generation, you always have to be a little bit creative depending on how your generated room can be interacted with, and how it should look like. Some questions you might want to ask yourself at some point:

1. does your room have to be convex? Can you deal with rooms that have holes in the middle? Maybe they are even desired? *I'm going to use the term "convex" loosely here, for lack of a better word, to describe a shape where each point is on the "outside"*
2. how many exits should a room potentially have? 1-4? Should this number be dependent on the seed, or will it be supplied by whatever algorithm generates the level layout?
3. are the exits always in the center of their respective side? eg. top center, bottom center?

The image you supplied above is special, in that it is fully convex, and it has exactly 2 potential exits on opposite sides. This  particular generation is relatively easy to replicate: Imagine it as a stack of blocks of varying width and height. All you have to do is generate the correct amount of random blocks and place them on top of each other randomly. Just make sure your blocks overlap sufficiently so there is a still a path from bottom to top.

[image]

Connecting 2 sides is simple: just stack your blocks from bottom to top and you will already have 2 potential exits.

Both other sides could be connected by either just straight up placing tiles from the respective side toward the center until they touch the room, or, which I find a more interesting idea: overlaying a second iteration of the same algorithm rotated by 90 degrees. This solution might generate holes/pillars though, which might not be desired.